# javascript not working in mvccontrib grid

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json, mvccontrib-grid

```
<% Html.Grid(Model.InnerModel.ParamaterDetails)
            .Empty("No data available")
            .Columns(column =>
            {
                column.For(x => x.MinValue).Named("Possible Min Value");
                column.For(x => x.MaxValue).Named("Possible Max Value");
                column.For(x => x.ScoreValue).Named("Bespoke Score Value");
                column.For(x => "<input type='button' name='button' class='btn' id='editOpenDialog' value='Edit' onclick=javascript:editParametersDialog('" + x.ID + "'); />").DoNotEncode();
            }).Render(); %>


<%Html.EndForm(); %>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function editParametersDialog(ID) {
        // Go back to the server and get the data for the road card timetable
        $.ajax({
            url: "GetDetails",
            type: "POST",
            data: "ID=" + ID,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                UpdateEditDialog(data);
                $('#addEditDialog').dialog('open');
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrow) { alert(jqXHR); alert(textStatus); }
        });
    }

    function UpdateEditDialog(data) {
        $("#MinValue").val(data.MinValue);
        $("#MaxValue").val(data.MaxValue);
        $("#ScoreValue").val(data.ScoreValue);
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
    });

</script>

GetDetails above is in controller
 [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public JsonResult GetDetails (int ID)
        {
// some code here
}
```

The onclick call javascript:editParametersDialog  does not work. It does not get evoked.
Any clues what I might be doing wrong.

I can figure out that javascript:editParametersDialog does not turn BLUE which is normally the case.

Comment: Your code looks fine. What doesn't get invoked? The `editParametersDialog` javascript method or the `GetDetails` controller action?

Comment: I checked in Mozilla javascript debugger, the code gets evoked bt fails on the line to Open Dialog, with error : "Object does not support this property or method"

Comment: OK, so that's something entirely different from what you have asked initially. Please update your question with relevant details. It seems that you haven't included jQuery UI or that you haven't set a dialog to the `addEditDialog` DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="addEditDialog" ></div>

your code is ok but u didn't put 
<div id="addEditDialog"></div>
in the .aspx page. 

for show dialog box div tag is must. 
$('#addEditDialog').dialog('open');
using this code you say div tag is show as popup.
Do it and try this one again.
```